# Refactoring out default Asp.Net MVC helpers to their own file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to re-factor the helpers that come in the controllers of a default Asp.Net Core web application, into their own ControllerHelper class. These methods are in each controller and that doesn't meet the DRY principles. Here are the methods.

```
  #region Helpers

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

   public static IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl,
        IUrlHelper url, RedirectResult redirect)
    {
        if (url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            //this expects a method name off redirect?
            return redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }
    }
```

ModelState is in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding namespace

I would have to pass the ModelStateDictionary from the controller to the method, but am not sure how to do that. I can seem to find the ModelStateDictionary in the controller to pass to the method.

How do I pass that ModelStateDictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelStateDictionary` is a public property of `ControllerBase` abstract class, from which the `Controller` abstract class inherit and all your controllers inherit from this `Controller` class. So you can access it like `this.ModelSate` inside a controller to pass it to your custom helper method call.

Add a parameter to your method of type `ModelStateDictionary`

```
public void AddErrors(ModelStateDictionary modelState,IdentityResult result)
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        modelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
    }
}
```

and call it from controller class like, pass `this.ModelState` as the value for your first parameter

```
yourHelperClassObject.AddErrors(this.ModelState,identityResultObject);
```

Comment: Thanks..I was close, I did add the ModelStateDictionary parameter but was confused what to pass it. Trying to figure out how to pass this **return Redirect(returnUrl)** Redirect to move the RedirectToLocal method now

Comment: @Shyju...please see the updated post, I had incorrectly copied the wrong second method in the question. Tried passing a RedirectResult for Redirect(returnUrl) but the parameter expects a method name

Comment: It should be `return redirect;` because `redirect` param is already a redirect result. BTW, you should not be editing a question to a totally new question. It will not help anyone for the future.

Comment: I also suggest you to keep these kinds of methods to a BaseController ,and inherit from that. This is more like the controller level stuff. That is exactly why the MVC folks kept it there instead of a separate helper class.

Comment: Noted: I am leaving those methods as private helpers in the controller